# getContent() returns Blob PDF-body in console, but HTML page (rendered like PDF) in Email service code

Tags: pdf, apex-email-service, getcontent

First at all: Happy New Year to you and your family. I wish you all the best in new 2014 year.

And about my case:

I use 'MyPdfRenderingPage.**getContent();**' method to get Blob PDF-body, create PDF attachment and sent it by mail.

And a code (please see below) works great in  Console's Execute Anonimous Window. It creates a mail with PDF file attached which I can open later.

But if I insert the same piece of code in my Email service (it receives a mail, creates a record and returns new mail with PDF attachment), it doesn't work correctly. I receive the mail, but can't open PDF attachment.

So I checked what does that Blob return content? If to execute 'MyPdfRenderingPage.getContent();' method in Email service, it returns HTML file with JS script inside leads to MyPdfRenderingPage.

In both cases the code runs by the same user, i did check it as well.

I have no idea what is wrong here...

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

And that code below

---

```
Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(5);

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'my@mail.com'};

mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

mail.setReplyTo('my@mail.com');

mail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');

mail.setSubject('New Record Created : ' + newRecords[0].id);

mail.setBccSender(true);

mail.setUseSignature(false);

mail.setPlainTextBody('Your new record has been created.');

mail.setHtmlBody('Your new record has been created.');


    PageReference pdf = Page.MyPDFpage;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id', (String)newRecords[0].id);
    pdf.getParameters().put('position', '1');
    pdf.setRedirect(true);

    Blob pageContent = pdf.getContent();

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName('PrintThisPDF.pdf');
    efa.setBody(pageContent);                                                          

mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});                                                         

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Comment: great question Denis - who or what exactly is sending email _to_ this email service? An external system? a person? Or Apex code authored by you?

Comment: What about an Email Template with an expressed Attachment utilising a VF Component to render the content? (you can set the Email Template Id in your code, and thus the body, attachment etc is expressed via the template).

Comment: Dear Andrew Fawcett! Thanks a lot for your comment. Probably your great idea is close to an idea in the second answer below. I will try it later - I'm exhausted today. Hopefully we will not face with 'Session ID is null' problem, if to go this way.

Answer (score 7):

You can't get the PDF content unfortunately.

While Email Services do run under a 'Context User', you will notice that `UserInfo.getSessionId()` returns null from any InboundEmailHandler implementation you may have.

The HTML with JavaScript is serving up a client-side redirect to a Salesforce login page. This is because `pdf.getContent()` runs in a different execution context that *also* lacks a Session ID at the time of making the request to render the page.

Salesforce have [documented this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm):

> This method can't be used in <sub>[...]</sub> Apex email services

Comment: Dear user320! I appreciate greatly your answer! Happy New Year for you! Your answer surprised me - it has been the first time I see that SFDC can not do something. In my case we expect emails both from an external system and probably users. They should send a mail with CSV file to be parsed. Email service parses the file, makes records and returns (good formated, good-looking) file (pdf is perfect for that) which contents pictures with QR codes. (please see continuation in the next comment)

Comment: I expect a lot of situations in coming projects, when an Email service should send a mail reply with 'on the fly' created PDF file. And what to do? Can we SAVE that PDF rendered page like a PDF-Attachment or PDF-Document to our Org and than attach it to the mail? Can we do it in Email service execution context? Or one more idea: is it possible to run APEX code within any Session programmatically, in other words without a real person login in the system? Thank you so much for your great help.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider that the lowest common denominator in this scenario, is the creation of the new record - it might be worth considering a Workflow Rule to send out the email with the attachment using a Visualforce Email Template.  That way, you don't have to write Apex code to send the email (thus preserving your daily limit).

Firstly, you'd need to create a Visualforce Email Template, for example:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="New Record Created {!relatedTo.Id}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Account">

    <messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="{!relatedTo.Name}.pdf">
        Place the Visualforce in MyPDFPage here     
    </messaging:attachment>

    <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
        Your new record has been created.   
    </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

And then refer to that in a simple workflow rule that 'fires' everytime a new record is created (i.e. the thought being, your email service creates your new record but you delegate the sending of the email/attachment to workflow upon record creation), for example:

[image]

There may be other reasons that exclude the use of workflow, but I thought it worth a mention as its often overlooked.

Comment: Dear Phil Hawthorn! Thanks a lot for your great answer. I will try it later- I'm exhausted today. Hopefully we will not face with 'Session ID is null' problem, if to go this way. I hope so much... Plus we still need to put parameters in the PDFpage, I do hope all that works together...

Comment: Good luck @DenisBrown, let us know how you get on.