# Send email on single button click for custom object

Tags: email, custom-object, custom-button

I want a button on a custom object (which is similar to standard Contact object) to send email. On button click, an email should be sent. I tried with **location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Temporary_Contact__c.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Temporary_Contact__c.Temporary_Contact_Email__c}&template_id=00X1F000000DbdC&p5=&save=1');** but on button click, an email screen page appears to select additional details. Like this-[image]
I do not want this screen. I appended **&save=1**, yet the screen appears. Please someone guide me how to send email just on a single button click!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it is not. The title to that link is misleading!

Comment: Well, what does your url look like when it enters this page? Looks like the "temporary contact email" field is blank for this particular record. Also can you make it a normal URL button/link, no JavaScript and see what happens? Maybe there's some urlencoding happening to "@" symbol that confuses the form. Also remove "save=1" for now, let's see the page with params passed (or not) before it attempts the send.

Comment: Thanks for your response @eyescream. The URL on button click looks like this- https://salesforce-instance/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/a0r1F0000005EgA&p3_lkid=a0r1F0000005EgA&p24=abc@abc.com&template_id=00X1F000000Dboe&p5=&save=1. Is it possible to exclude the email details page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start with just `/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?p24=abc@abc.com&template_id=00X1F000000Dboe` and see if it populates the "Additional To" (even if the email template will not merge properly because it lacks the custom object's id & save parameter).
2. If it works - add back the p3_lkid and see if it breaks (I'm not even sure where did you get p3 from, contact should go to p2. And your original url doesn't mention it.)

I suspect the object is not configured to "allow activities" (incl email). Is this a sandbox? Did you remember to check Setup->Deliverability after refresh & allow all email?

Generally - add `&save=1` as last step, once you have everything else prepopulating OK.

More info: [Sending Email using Email Author in custom button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78925/sending-email-using-email-author-in-custom-button)

Comment: Yes it is a sandbox. Object is configured to "Allow Activities". Deliverability Access Level is set to "All Email". What **&save=1**  does, could you please explain?

Comment: Simulates clicking "send", "submit", "save" etc buttons on various standard SF pages (right click the send button and inspect it's `name` in html). After successful send you'll go back to retURL or if none specified - home page. Generally I'm advising to leave it off until you're sure other parameters work OK, add it as last step of the automation

Comment: Oh thank you. I referred this [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006tqzAAA). Its mentioned there in a single click the mail can be sent. Is it possible to send email just on a button click?

Comment: I tried your suggestion of **/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?p24=abc@abc.com&template_id=00X1F000000Dboe** but got this error **A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: Invalid regular expression flags**. Please help me!

Comment: I said "Also can you make it a normal URL button/link, no JavaScript"... You might suffer form some urlencodign issues related to escaping special characters. You don't need JS for this functionality. And yes, it's possible to automate it 100%, there must be something simple you're not doing.

Comment: I did try with URL button/link but I receive the **URL no longer exists** standard salesforce error.